# What is the meaning of vector<Node<int>*>?

Tags: c++, sorting, linked-list, heap, min-heap

I was solving a question on merging k sorted linked lists and I came across this `vector<Node<int>*>`:

```
Node<int>* mergeKLists(vector<Node<int>*> &listArray);
```

I want to know if it is a declaration of all the linked lists, if it is how it has been declared?

Answer (score 2):

> what is the meaning of vector<Node*>

It's a vector of pointers to Nodes, where each Node pointed to is the first node of a linked list. The size of the vector would be `K`, corresponding to `K` linked lists. Each Node has one data member, an integer.

> Node<int>* mergeKLists(vector<Node<int>*> &listArray);

The function merges the `K` linked lists and returns a single list. I don't know why the name listArray was chosen since the parameter is a vector.

Based on the comment below, these are single linked lists.

Comment: here is the definition for the node:                                                                  
  class Node {
        public:
        T data;
        Node* next;

        Node(T data) {
            next = NULL;
            this->data = data;
        }

        ~Node() {
            if (next != NULL) {
                delete next;
            }
        }
    };

Answer (score 0):

- `Node<int>` is a linked list node.
- `Node<int>*` is a pointer to a linked list node.
- `std::vector<Node<int>*>` is a vector of pointers to a linked list node.

In practical terms, if you don't implement a `LinkedList` class, the pointer to a linked list node  could be the linked list itself, or a sublist. So `std::vector<Node<int>*>` would then be a vector of lists.

For example, you could implement `mergeKLists` in a way that joins all the linked lists in `listArray` together.

[[Demo]](https://godbolt.org/z/4Kz6G6GGP)

```cpp
#include <fmt/core.h>
#include <vector>

template <typename T>
struct Node {
    T data;
    Node* next;
};

void mergeKLists(std::vector<Node<int>*>& listArray) {
    if (listArray.empty()) {
        return;
    }
    for (size_t i{ 0 }; i < listArray.size() - 1; ++i) {
        auto ptr{ listArray[i] };
        while (ptr->next) {
            ptr = ptr->next;
        }
        ptr->next = listArray[i+1];
    }
}

void printList(const Node<int>* list) {
    fmt::print("[ ");
    for (auto ptr{ list }; ptr != nullptr; ptr = ptr->next) {
        fmt::print("{} ", ptr->data);
    }
    fmt::print("]");
}

int main() {
    Node<int> m2{2, nullptr};
    Node<int> m1{1, &m2};
    Node<int> n2{4, nullptr};
    Node<int> n1{3, &n2};
    std::vector<Node<int>*> lA{ &m1, &n1 };
    mergeKLists(lA);
    printList(lA[0]);
}

// Outputs: [ 1 2 3 4 ]
```

---

Creating a `LinkedList` class, and doing some encapsulation work, would help to make the code simpler and easier to read:

[[Demo]](https://godbolt.org/z/3E9Mc48qM)

```cpp
template <typename T>
class LinkedList {
public:
    LinkedList(Node<T>* head)
        : head_{ head }
    {}
    auto head() const {
        return head_;
    }
    auto head() {
        return head_;
    }
    auto tail() {
        auto ptr{ head_ };
        while (ptr and ptr->next) {
            ptr = ptr->next;
        }
        return ptr;
    }
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const LinkedList<T>& l) {
        os << "[ ";
        for (auto ptr{ l.head() }; ptr != nullptr; ptr = ptr->next) {
            os << ptr->data << " ";
        }
        return os << "]";
    }
private:
    Node<T>* head_;
};

template <typename T>
using LinkedListVector = std::vector<LinkedList<T>>;

template <typename T>
void mergeKLists(LinkedListVector<T>& v) {
    if (v.empty()) {
        return;
    }
    for (size_t i{ 0 }; i < v.size() - 1; ++i) {
        v[i].tail()->next = v[i+1].head();
    }
}
```